# Manipulation of array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash, data-manipulation

How can I manipulate the specific object ? , here is my example.

```
    "lead_tags": [{
        "tag_id": 8616,
        "user_id": 622,
        "tag_name": null,
        "tag_description": null,
        "user_tag_id": 2147483647,
        "user_tags": null
    }, {
        "tag_id": 8656,
        "user_id": 622,
        "tag_name": null,
        "tag_description": null,
        "user_tag_id": 2147483647,
        "user_tags": null
    }, {
        "tag_id": 8742,
        "user_id": 622,
        "tag_name": null,
        "tag_description": null,
        "user_tag_id": 1249,
        "user_tags": {
            "user_tag_id": 1249,
            "user_id": 622,
            "tag_name": "Testtesttest"
        }   }, {
        "tag_id": 8767,
        "user_id": 622,
        "tag_name": null,
        "tag_description": null,
        "user_tag_id": 1262,
        "user_tags": {
            "user_tag_id": 1262,
            "user_id": 622,
            "tag_name": "t"
        }   }]
```

first I need to filter all the userTags that equal to `null`

I use Filter to not return the value of user_tags: null

```js
var lead_tags = [{
        "tag_id": 8616,
        "user_id": 622,
        "tag_name": null,
        "tag_description": null,
        "user_tag_id": 2147483647,
        "user_tags": null
    }, {
        "tag_id": 8656,
        "user_id": 622,
        "tag_name": null,
        "tag_description": null,
        "user_tag_id": 2147483647,
        "user_tags": null
    }, {
     
        "user_id": 622,
        "tag_name": null,
        "tag_description": null,
        "user_tag_id": 1249,
        "user_tags": {
            "user_tag_id": 1249,
            "user_id": 622,
            "tag_name": "Testtesttest",
            "tag_id": 8742
        }   }, {
       
        "user_id": 622,
        "tag_name": null,
        "tag_description": null,
        "user_tag_id": 1262,
        "user_tags": {
            "user_tag_id": 1262,
            "user_id": 622,
            "tag_name": "t",
            "tag_id": 8767
        }   }];
        
        
        
 var filter = _.filter(lead_tags, (data, index) => {
   return data.user_tags != null;
 });


console.log(filter);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Now I need to get the tag_id in the beginning and return the data looks like this

```
"lead_tags": [{

    "user_id": 622,
    "tag_name": null,
    "tag_description": null,
    "user_tag_id": 1249,
    "user_tags": {
        "user_tag_id": 1249,
        "user_id": 622,
        "tag_name": "Testtesttest",
        "tag_id": 8742
    }
}, {

    "user_id": 622,
    "tag_name": null,
    "tag_description": null,
    "user_tag_id": 1262,
    "user_tags": {
        "user_tag_id": 1262,
        "user_id": 622,
        "tag_name": "t",
        "tag_id": 8767
    }
}]
```

I hope you could help me in manipulating the data.

Comment: You may want to look at `Array.prototype.filter` and `Array.prototype.map`. Read about those functions, write some code, and post back with follow up questions when you get stuck.

Comment: Actually I'm stuck how can I manipulate the specific object :)

Comment: Can you clarify what this means - "Now I need to get the tag_id in the beginning and return the data looks like this"? I don't see what you've changed from one example to the next.

Comment: as you can see there's an array of object inside of object there's another object, in the first object there's tag_id and i need to move the tag_id inside of object number 2 

(array of object 1 inside there's object 2)

Comment: You don't need to duplicate your unprocessed data and the result as we can see it from the snippet code.

Comment: @StefansArya you mean the last snippet ? code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let lead_tags = [{
    "tag_id": 8616,
    "user_id": 622,
    "tag_name": null,
    "tag_description": null,
    "user_tag_id": 2147483647,
    "user_tags": null
}, {
    "tag_id": 8656,
    "user_id": 622,
    "tag_name": null,
    "tag_description": null,
    "user_tag_id": 2147483647,
    "user_tags": null
}, {
    "tag_id": 8742,
    "user_id": 622,
    "tag_name": null,
    "tag_description": null,
    "user_tag_id": 1249,
    "user_tags": {
        "user_tag_id": 1249,
        "user_id": 622,
        "tag_name": "Testtesttest"
    }
}, {
    "tag_id": 8767,
    "user_id": 622,
    "tag_name": null,
    "tag_description": null,
    "user_tag_id": 1262,
    "user_tags": {
        "user_tag_id": 1262,
        "user_id": 622,
        "tag_name": "t"
    }
}];


let userTagsArrObj = [];

for (let tagIndex = 0; tagIndex < lead_tags.length; tagIndex++) {
    const tagObject = lead_tags[tagIndex],
        { tag_id, user_tags } = tagObject;

    if (user_tags) {
      user_tags['tag_id'] = tag_id;
      userTagsArrObj.push(user_tags);
    }
}


console.log(userTagsArrObj);
```

For future reference

```js
let lead_tags = [{
    "tag_id": 8616,
    "user_id": 622,
    "tag_name": null,
    "tag_description": null,
    "user_tag_id": 2147483647,
    "user_tags": null
}, {
    "tag_id": 8656,
    "user_id": 622,
    "tag_name": null,
    "tag_description": null,
    "user_tag_id": 2147483647,
    "user_tags": null
}, {
    "tag_id": 8742,
    "user_id": 622,
    "tag_name": null,
    "tag_description": null,
    "user_tag_id": 1249,
    "user_tags": {
        "user_tag_id": 1249,
        "user_id": 622,
        "tag_name": "Testtesttest"
    }
}, {
    "tag_id": 8767,
    "user_id": 622,
    "tag_name": null,
    "tag_description": null,
    "user_tag_id": 1262,
    "user_tags": {
        "user_tag_id": 1262,
        "user_id": 622,
        "tag_name": "t"
    }
}];

let result = lead_tags.filter((tagObject) => {
    if (tagObject.user_tags) {
        tagObject.user_tags['tag_id'] = tagObject.tag_id;
        return tagObject;
    }
});

console.log(result);
```

More Optimize

```js
let lead_tags = [{
    "tag_id": 8616,
    "user_id": 622,
    "tag_name": null,
    "tag_description": null,
    "user_tag_id": 2147483647,
    "user_tags": null
}, {
    "tag_id": 8656,
    "user_id": 622,
    "tag_name": null,
    "tag_description": null,
    "user_tag_id": 2147483647,
    "user_tags": null
}, {
    "tag_id": 8742,
    "user_id": 622,
    "tag_name": null,
    "tag_description": null,
    "user_tag_id": 1249,
    "user_tags": {
        "user_tag_id": 1249,
        "user_id": 622,
        "tag_name": "Testtesttest"
    }
}, {
    "tag_id": 8767,
    "user_id": 622,
    "tag_name": null,
    "tag_description": null,
    "user_tag_id": 1262,
    "user_tags": {
        "user_tag_id": 1262,
        "user_id": 622,
        "tag_name": "t"
    }
}];


let userTags = [];

for (let tagIndex = 0; tagIndex < lead_tags.length; tagIndex++) {
    const tagObject = lead_tags[tagIndex],
        tagId = tagObject.tag_id;

    let userTag = tagObject.user_tags;

    if (userTag) {
      userTag['tag_id'] = tagId;
      userTags.push(userTag);
    }
}

console.log(userTags);
```

Answer (score 2):

Hope this work

```
var lead_tags = [{
    "tag_id": 8616,
    "user_id": 622,
    "tag_name": null,
    "tag_description": null,
    "user_tag_id": 2147483647,
    "user_tags": null
}, {
    "tag_id": 8656,
    "user_id": 622,
    "tag_name": null,
    "tag_description": null,
    "user_tag_id": 2147483647,
    "user_tags": null
}, {

    "user_id": 622,
    "tag_name": null,
    "tag_description": null,
    "user_tag_id": 1249,
    "user_tags": {
        "user_tag_id": 1249,
        "user_id": 622,
        "tag_name": "Testtesttest",
        "tag_id": 8742
    }   }, {

    "user_id": 622,
    "tag_name": null,
    "tag_description": null,
    "user_tag_id": 1262,
    "user_tags": {
        "user_tag_id": 1262,
        "user_id": 622,
        "tag_name": "t",
        "tag_id": 8767
    }   }];



 var filter = lead_tags.filter(data => data.user_tags != null);
 let result = [];
   filter.forEach(el => {
      result = [
        ...result,
        {
          tag_id: el['user_tags']['tag_id'],
          user_id: el['user_id'],
          ...el,
         }
      ]
   });
   console.log(result);



const result2 = filter.reduce((acc, curr) => {
     return acc.concat({
          tag_id: curr['user_tags']['tag_id'],
          user_id: curr['user_id'],
          ...curr,
         })}, []);
   console.log(result2)
```

Comment: WOW Thanks man, so you are using spread operator ? and create an object name ?

Comment: yes, i'm using spread operator, another way is using `reduce`, i updated my code

Comment: I put my code also for shorter method, But thanks man, I helps me also or giving me an idea.